# Boa prática ao carregar uma div com dados do banco, usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Qual a melhor forma de montar uma div com jQuery
Exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type:'post',        
    dataType: 'json',   
    url: 'listAllForum',
    success: function(dados){
        for(var i = 0; dados.length > i; i++){

            $('#post-forum').append('<strong>Usuario Fulano de Tal</strong> - Data: 00/00 <br>' + 
                    dados[i].idForum + ' - '+ dados[i].message + '<br> <br>');
        }
    }
});
```

});

Por exemplo: quero que cada mensagem fique com uma cor diferente para facilitar a leitura.
O nome do usuário coloque as tags  para dar um destaque, mas está certo fazer isso dentro do for do ajax ?
Se eu quiser colocar um link  para redirecionar para um @RequestMapping, onde colocaria o href ?

Comment: Seria mais interessante criar uma função específica para trabalhar com os dados caso queria fazer desta maneira. Mas, na minha opinião, melhor mesmo seria a utilização de template-engines, exemplo: http://handlebarsjs.com/ . pois assim você já deixaria o código pronto e mais fácil de manutenção.

Comment: Boa tarde, estou começando agora, como poderia montar uma function separada para remover o HTML de dentro do jQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

Como você não usa um template-ensines, melhor forma seria adicionar algumas classes de cores no seu CSS, e após a requisição do ajax você retornar em seu objeto json a cor certa para cada post.

$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'listAllForum',
    success: function(dados){
        for(var i = 0; dados.length > i; i++){

```
        //Get cores
        var varCor = dados.cor;
        var contentPosts =  $('#post-forum');         

        contentPosts.append('<div class="' +  varCor + '">Usuario Fulano de Tal</strong> - Data: 00/00 <br>' + 
                dados[i].idForum + ' - '+ dados[i].message + '</div>');
    }
}
```

});